# How to rename a default folder in the Windows user library

Tags: windows, windows-10, libraries, user-folders

In Windows 10, there are several folders in the user library (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, Videos):

[image: folders]

How can I rename them?

Comment: Why don't you customize your library with your own created folders.

Comment: @Scorpion99 Because I want to make use of the default folders. Why create new links, if already links exist.

Comment: Right-click --> rename?

Comment: it exists in Windows 7, and I don't have Windows 10 in front of me to test it right this second.  Hence why I asked you in a _comment_, in an attempt to clarify if it worked for you or not.  Please stop telling us how to behave.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The libraries don't have a Rename option on Windows 10 (but it was a good idea to check). Fortunately, the `LocalizedResourceName` entry in `desktop.ini` can be used here - see my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set your Folder Options to show hidden and system files. You'll then see a file called `desktop.ini` in each user folder. The one in Desktop contains this:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21769
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-183
```

Other folders may have more entries, but they're not relevant here. The `LocalizedResourceName` line is what lets Windows know to display a translated folder name. You can change its value to a constant string, like so:

```
LocalizedResourceName=Top of the Desk
```

Consider making a back-up of these `desktop.ini` files in case you want to put the localizable default back. You can also use a semicolon (`;`) to comment out lines in INI files.

Once you're done, log off and back on. (Restarting `explorer.exe` is not enough.) Your custom name will appear in *Quick access*, *This PC*, and every place that supports localized folder names.

[image: new names in Explorer]

Comment: When referencing shell32.dll: `-21769 = Desktop`; `-21770 = Documents`; `-21790 = Music`; `-21779 = Pictures`; `-21791 = Videos`; `-21798 = Downloads`

Comment: Note that this doesn't seem to work if you relocalized a folder to an HDD's root. It would show "E:\" for example, ignoring the name instead of displaying "Music"

Answer (score 3):

No need to edit the `desktop.ini` file directly. While the Folder shortcuts under **This PC** don't offer the `Rename` command in their context menus, their corresponding target folders do.
So, from **This PC**:

- Right-click the folder shortcut & select **Properties**
- Select the **Location** tab
- Click `Find Target...`

[image]

- The parent of the target folder opens with the target selected

[image]

Fron there it can be renamed through any of the standard methods --- all of which actually modify the `desktop.ini` file rather than actually renaming the folder in the filesystem.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 10 if you have changed you downloads to another HDD drive for example E:\Downloads to rename your default folder name just delete the desktop.ini file but make a backup first and then restart the default folder should change to whatever you have named your downloads folder

Comment: Hi William, this answer is going to need significant improvements in details and formatting to be acceptable. And periods, maybe some commas. Please revise this to add some value to the OP question, and already accepted answers, or this may be flagged for removal.